# External string does not exist error while trying to deploy through Jenkins

Tags: deployment, salesforce, jenkins-groovy

We have repo with salesforce code. Goal is to deploy it to scratch org and launch tests.

Below is the error as we are getting while running a Jenkins pipeline for common libraries.

```
Error src/main/java/com/spartasystems/twd/security/PermissionGuard.cls External string does 
not exist: PERMISSION_DENIED_AN_OBJECT (27:82)
Error src/main/java/com/spartasystems/twd/security/PermissionGuard.cls External string does 
not exist: PERMISSION_DENIED_A_FIELD (29:82)
ERROR running force:source:deploy: Deploy failed.
```

My deploy code looks like as shows below:

```
stage('MDAPI Deploy To Scratch Org'){
        sh 'ls -al'
        sh 'cat sfdx-project.json'
        sh 'cat src/labels/*'
        SFDX.deployMDAPISourceCodeToScratchOrg("./abc/src/");
        SFDX.deployMDAPISourceCodeToScratchOrg("./xyz/src/");
        sh 'rm src/main/java/com/company/twd/util/DebuggingUtil'
        sh 'sfdx force:source:deploy -x src/main/resources/package.xml'
}
```

Here is the package.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomLabels</name>
    </types>
    <version>49.0</version>
</Package>
```

Can anyone help me here as I am stuck and unable to fix this issue ?
I have got a response from Salesforce Stack Exchange that this might be something related to third-party java library . I am unable to understand whether there is an issue with Labels missing in Salesforce org or what else.

Kindly help me with this.

Comment: Does the custom labels file contain these 2, PERMISSION_DENIED_AN_OBJECT & PERMISSION_DENIED_A_FIELD ?

Comment: @eyescream we are unable to find out the location of the labels :( we can then check whether these two components are present in labels or not and if not we can add it then. Thats the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using custom label then 'Custom label' must already exist in targeting environment(where you are deploying the code through Jenkins).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you understand my question from comments.

If the apex class `PermissionGuard` contains references like `Label.PERMISSION_DENIED_AN_OBJECT` then:

- that "custom label" must already exist in the target environment
- or your deployment must be creating that custom label in the same action that creates/updates this class.

It's not a Jenkins problem. You're pulling the files from some Git repo or locally on filesystem? If the developer committed to Git only the class but not the custom labels file - shout at the dev that this is not deployable. Whether to scratch org, to sandbox or to production.

The `labels\CustomLabels.labels` file will look similar to this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomLabels xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <labels>
        <fullName>CommunityAccessSuspended</fullName>
        <categories>Community, Login</categories>
        <language>en_US</language>
        <protected>false</protected>
        <shortDescription>CommunityAccessSuspended</shortDescription>
        <value>Your access is disabled. Please contact your site administrator.</value>
    </labels>
</CustomLabels>
```

If the dev doesn't know how to download the fresh file from org, `sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve -r ./mdapi -u yourUsername@yourCompany.com -k ./path/to/package.xml` should be a good start.